# Can't change .NET Target Framework Version in VS 2015 C++ project

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2015, clr

As the title says, I want to change the .NET Target Framework Version for my C++ project. I'm trying to compile with the /clr command which I think should enable it?

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

I'm trying to build a DLL for use in Unity and I want to be able to select the proper framework.

I've tried changing the information in the .vxproj file but I can't find the right tag and when I add it myself it throws errors.

EDIT:

this is the code that contains the methods that can be called in C# to use the C++ code I've written before. I only edited the .h file of the CLR Class library (so the .cpp file is only including the header which should be fine I think)

```
#pragma once
#include "PortAudioManager.h"

using namespace System;

namespace PortAudioWrapper {

public ref class PortAudioManaged
{
private:
    PortAudioManager* audioManager;
public:
    PortAudioManaged() : audioManager(new PortAudioManager()) {
    }

    virtual ~PortAudioManaged() {
        this->!PortAudioManaged();
    }

    // = Object.Finalize
    !PortAudioManaged() {
        delete audioManager;
        audioManager = nullptr;
    }

    void openStreamManaged() {
        audioManager->openStream();
    }

    void stopStreamManaged() {
        audioManager->stopStream();
    }
};
}
```

Comment: What if you click on the **Common Language Runtime Support** row in the dialog? Does it show a `...` with more options?

Comment: Nope. Only this: http://i.imgur.com/Clopmy1.jpg

Comment: This setting was added in VS2015 but is not implemented.  There are several very icky problems to solve with multi-targeting in C++/CLI projects.  Fairly unlikely they'll ever get addressed.  It is really rather best to use a project template from the Visual C++ > CLR node to get your project started.  By far the best way to get all configurations and settings right, at least the setting will show you the version number you picked.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to follow the guide at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx

The .NET framework you can target in C++ is dependent on the toolset you choose.  You may find it easier to just download an older version of VS that supports the framework you're looking to work with.

In project file I just created the section looks like the below:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
   <ProjectGuid>{48ACEC98-3369-486F-9033-8C433D408570}</ProjectGuid>
   <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
   <Keyword>ManagedCProj</Keyword>
   <RootNamespace>ClassLibrary1</RootNamespace>
   <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>8.1</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I can't seem to find that entry in the vcxproj file.

Comment: Maybe deleted during your other attempts?  Could try creating a new project and copy it form there.  In one I made just now it looks like what I just edited into answer.

Comment: Did you create a c++ DLL project? I tried with a new project created like this: New Project -> Win32 Console Application -> (options) Empty Project, DLL, unchecked Precompiled Headers. This way, there is no tag for the TargetFramework in the vcxproj file

Comment: Try New Project -> Visual C++ -> CLR -> Class Library

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So, I've created a CLR class library as you told me. This time I did it in Visual Studio 2008 to make sure that my .NET framework is "old enough" so that it works in Unity (is how I think of it, this might be wrong).
Now, everything compiles properly with the .NET 2.0 framework but once again when I import the dll in my Unity project it doesn't seem to find the namespace I've used (and so, the connection to the unmanaged code) + I've edited the main question with the code I use in the CLR project

Answer (score 2):

Using VS2015, I had to upgrade the .Net target of a managed C++ DLL from 3.5 to 4.5.1. In the Configuration Properties-General settings, the ".Net Target Framework Version" is greyed out and its value box is not editable.

1. Open the Name.vcxproj file in notepad.
2. Navigate to: "<"PropertyGroup Label="Globals" ""
3. Add: "<"TargetFrameworkVersion""v4.5.1"<"/TargetFrameworkVersion"
4. Save the updated project file, and reload into VSS2015.

NOTE: Remove the "" around the angle brackets. 
Then when the project is reloaded into VS2015, you can see the .Net version listed in settings.  In my case it was V4.5.1.